# StencilJS : how to export custom types from a components library?

Tags: typescript, web-component, stenciljs

I made a library (named `sphere-stencil`) of Stencil components that use some custom types (in `sphere.ts`). The library compiles and tests without error, but when I use it in an application I have compilation errors like

> TypeScript: ../sphere-stencil/dist/types/components.d.ts:12:25
> Cannot find module 'sphere' or its corresponding type declarations.

even if the application doesn't use anything exported by `sphere.ts`

sphere.ts is in a src/utils subdir of my library, the library's tsconfig.js contains

```
"paths": {
  "*": ["./src/*", "./src/utils/*"]
}
```

If generates dist/esm/sphere.js, and dist/types/utils/sphere.d.ts

However in dist/types/components.d.ts I have

```
import { JobData } from "sphere";
```

without mention to the utils/ folder,
and dist/index.js contains only

```
export * from './esm/index.js';
```

which is empty ...

what do I miss to properly export (or import) the custom types along with the library ?
Thanks !

Comment: If I remember correctly you'll have to explicitly export it from your `./src/index.ts`.

Comment: thanks. tried  both 
export * from './utils/sphere'; 
and export * as sphere from './utils/sphere';
still same errors when compiling the application, see below @Tiago's answer

Comment: I see `import { JobData } from "sphere";` - I'm confused because that shouldn't work. The module name "sphere" (with no `./`) isn't relative so I don't see why that would compile at all. Where is this module `sphere`? 
It seems like any import from there should actually be like `import { JobData } from "./sphere";`

Comment: Also, I don't know if it's related but I see no reason for the './src/utils/*' path in tsconfig.js, it's redundant. You already include everything in ./src.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the the previous (correct) response:

Also make sure your package.json is properly configured:

```json
{
  "main": "dist/index.cjs.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "es2015": "dist/esm/index.mjs",
  "es2017": "dist/esm/index.mjs",
  "types": "dist/types/components.d.ts",
  "collection": "dist/collection/collection-manifest.json",
  "collection:main": "dist/collection/index.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/<libname>/<libname>.esm.js",
}
```

where libname is what you have configured in stencil.config.json under namespace

Comment: Done as you and @thomas  say, but still have the same errors when compiling the application that uses the library:

[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: ../sphere-stencil/dist/types/components.d.ts:13:27
           Cannot find module 'sphere' or its corresponding type declarations.

     L12:  import { JobData } from "sphere";
   
See ? the components.d.ts imports from "sphere" but it should be from "utils/sphere", isn't it ?

Comment: The package.json structure changed in Stencil 2, see https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/main/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#dist-packagejson . The config from `@ionic/core` might also be a good reference: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/main/core/package.json